# AddressVerify php error 10002

Tags: api, paypal

i try to Verify pay pal mail adresses with code

```
$this->_errors = array();
        if (empty($method)) {
            $this->_errors = array('Method does not exist');
            return false;
        }

    $requestParams = array(
        'METHOD' => $method,
        'VERSION' => $this->_version
    ) + $this->_credentials;

    if (is_array($params)) {
        $request = http_build_query($requestParams + $params);
    } else {
        $request = http_build_query($requestParams) . $params;
    }

    $curlOptions = array (
        CURLOPT_URL            => $this->_endPoint,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO         => $this->_certificate,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Code is right-it work on another project, but when i try call AddressVerify method from paypal API i have 10002 error-"You do not have permissions to make this API call".
I using "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp" adress for connect and still have that error.
Any one know what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The AddressVerify API call is not enabled on every account by default.  If this is for the sandbox, if you can provide me with the email address of the test sandbox seller account that you wish to have this enabled for, I can enable it on your account.  If this is for a live account, you would need to contact PayPal Merchant Services and submit a request to have this enabled.

Comment: I did not find a test sandbox seller account with this email address.  Make sure this is the email address of the test sandbox seller acocunt, and not the email address that you are logging into developer.paypal.com with.

Comment: When i try login on sandbox site with my sandbox account
paypal-facilitator@issart.com and come in
My selling tools
i have infinite loading screen and can't take user pwd signature for sandbox api

Comment: I am having trouble getting this enabled on this account.  Can you try creating another business/pro account from within the developer account.  Once you have done this, can you provide the email address of the newly created account and I will try to enable this on the new account.